# How can I change the home page of a site in Orchard CMS based on rules such as the time of day, or the visitor's device?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I need to be able to dynamically set the home page of an Orchard site based on differing factors.

Normally, I could create rule providers or theme selectors to dynamically change the theme/ widgets on a page. However- some of the pages that need to be set as the home page are just normal MVC pages and therefore layer rules will not do in this case.

I've looked at the alias module, and think this would be a good starting point. For example, I could say when the user hits `/` and certain criteria are met, then route to `/controller/action/123` etc....

Ignoring the issue of how to implement the decision making logic, can anyone suggest the best way for me to achieve what I'm aiming to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to override the route for `"/"` to point to your custom controller. Make decision there and either perform a redirect, transfer the request or return varying results.

It could also be done on a lower level but this is way more complicated (using custom route implementation, route handler etc. - similar to what `Orchard.Alias` module does). Extending `Orchard.Alias` to take into account custom logic in addition to or replacing the current simple path-matching logic would be a way to go then.

Comment: I would really, really encourage you to rethink the design however: a given URL should in principle correspond to a single resource. Redirecting to different URLs from your home page based on these factors would work well, would be easier to set-up, and would be more correct from a web standpoint.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy From design and good practice standpoint, I couldn't agree more. But there may be a specific business requirement we don't know about, that forces OP to show varying content at the *root* URL, without redirection.

Comment: That's why we need more information about the specific scenario. But as long as we don't know what it is, in doubt I'll push for best practices. ;)

Comment: I'd agree that this should be avoided if possible, and I'd personally be partial to what Bertrand suggested re redirects. Unfortunately however- it's not what the client wants and until we can convince him otherwise our hands are tied.

Comment: Yup. In this case, just re-route / to your custom controller, put all the logic there and either transfer the request (Server.Transfer) or simply return varying results.